# Map subdomain to subdirectory and custom header to basic authentication

Tags: nginx, proxy, authentication, rewrite, subdomain

I have a client library I need to support that hardcodes a subdirectory and a custom header authentication method. The server already uses the subdirectory for something else, so I was thinking map a subdomain + the subdirectory to a different subdirectory. The server uses Basic authentication.

I have it correctly rewriting the subdomain to the alternate subdirectory, but I'm having trouble with authentication. I currently pass the base64 encoded "user:pass" in the custom header and tried `proxy_set_header` to set the auth header. How can I use the value from the custom header for basic authentication?

```
server {
    server_name subdomain.example.com;
    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;

    rewrite ^/hardcodesubdir/(.*)$ https://example.com/newsubdir/$1;
    proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic $http_x_custom_header";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working with proxy_pass inside a location

```
server {
    server_name subdomain.example.com;
    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;

    location /hardcodesubdir/ {
        proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic $http_x_custom_header";
        proxy_pass https://example.com/newsubdir/
    }
}
```